# How to use Emacs+ESS to access GNU R within docker including x11 without openssh-server

Tags: tramp, ess, r, x11, docker

I'm using `Debian Stable` (currently `Buster`) to do my programming in `GNU R`.
As an IDE I'm using both [`Nvim-R`](https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R) (a `vim`/`neovim`-plugin) as well as [`Emacs+ESS`](https://ess.r-project.org/) but not [`Rstudio`](https://www.rstudio.com/) (although it's a great IDE for getting started).

Since the stability of `Debian` comes with the price of not having the newest software versions available, I'm on the verge of changing my workflow to not install `GNU R` on my metal directly but to use a container as an intermediate layer.
I'm currently using docker as my virtualization layer with a preconfigured [`rocker`](https://www.rocker-project.org/) image for that (more precisely the [`r-base`](https://hub.docker.com/_/r-base) image).

While this works in principle (I'm able to access the R CLI), I'm having an issue: I cannot easily to use my IDEs with that.

I don't want to install `vim` or `Emacs` in the container but run this from my machine directly.
Using `Emacs` this means that I need to run an `openssh`-server in my container, connect via `Tramp` and then execute commands there as described [here](https://gtown-ds.netlify.app/2017/08/16/docker-emacs/).

My question: is connecting via `ssh` actually needed when using `Emacs+ESS` as an IDE or is there a more elegant solution?

---

Addendum: x11 is often a problem.
I found the [following solution](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/wiki/Allowing-GUI-windows) for running R directly and being able to plot (although I still need to try it):

```
## an alias for `docker run` that links the X11 device
alias docker-run-gui='XSOCK=/tmp/.X11-unix && XAUTH=/tmp/.docker.xauth && xauth nlist :0 | sed -e "s/^..../ffff/" | xauth -f $XAUTH nmerge - && docker run  -v $XSOCK:$XSOCK -v $XAUTH:$XAUTH -e XAUTHORITY=$XAUTH  -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY'

## Use that alias in defining an alias that runs R from the hadleyverse container
alias R='docker-run-gui --rm -it -P --user 1000 -v $(pwd):/home/rstudio/`basename $PWD` -w /home/rstudio/`basename $PWD` rocker/hadleyverse R'
```

Alternatively, [this](https://gitlab.b-data.ch/rocker/verse/-/tree/363b1773ada8c5b2e40d77e9da6af0388c6e6c8f/X11) (I assume from the same author) also looks interesting (if you don't want to use aliases).

From what I understand when using an IDE like `Emacs+ESS` (or maybe `Nvim-R`) that should also work.  The approach described [`here`](https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/r-containers-for-data-science/) didn't work for me (the `R`-function `capabilities()` showed `X11` was still `FALSE`).

Comment: the current version of R is available for Debian stable and testing, if you add the backport repositories as described here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/#supported-branches

Comment: @tyler: thanks for the link, that's helpful! But the issue I'm currently having is actually not with `GNU R` itself but with the R-package [`vitae`](https://github.com/mitchelloharawild/vitae) which requires a more recent version of `pandoc` (actually: `pandoc-citeproc`). From what I understand I could sidestap all of those issues by using a container with a more recent version of `Debian` (or `Alpine` or whatever).

Comment: perhaps you could side-step the issue by installing the latest pandoc directly from source instead: https://pandoc.org/installing.html#linux. I haven't used containers before, but what you're describing sounds a lot more complicated that installing a few programs from source

Comment: @Tyler: in principle you are right, but I'd also need all the [dependencies for this specific version of pandoc](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/pandoc) and that would lead to a mixture of packages from different Debian versions which does sound scary and is [not recommended](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian).

Comment: I'm suggesting you install Pandoc using the binary provided by Pandoc (see the link), not making a FrankenDebian. It sounds like the Pandoc binary is self-contained, and doesn't require any external dependencies (unless you choose to compile it yourself, which isn't necessary)

Comment: @Tyler: ah, ok, thanks for the clarification, I'll try that.